# was given too many arguments; it expects 1 (Perl)

Tags: perl

I've been working on a card game that gets your deck and picks 1 out of three powers cards but whenever I try to run it, it gives me an error

Error:

```
Error: In call to CPUser::addCards(), was given too many arguments; it expects 1 at Server/CPUser.pm line 427.
```

Line 427:

```
 if($intItem == 821){ #Adds Card Jitsu Cards for Classic 
             $self->addCards($self->buildStarterDeck); 
       }
```

and this the buildStarterDeck Method

```
method buildStarterDeck {

    sub get_cards;
    my (@stackone, @stacktwo) = get_cards;

    sub get_cards 
    {
        my @start_cards = (1, 6, 9, 14, 17, 20, 22, 23, 26);
        my @power_cards = (73, 81, 89);
        @power_cards = $power_cards[rand @power_cards];

    return (@start_cards, @power_cards);
    }
}
```

The addCard method is empty since I've been trying to figure out this error and I couldn't get any luck.

Comment: Where does `method` come from?

Comment: What? Perl uses Methods to make a function...

Comment: Which version of perl?

Comment: perl 5, version 18, subversion 1 (v5.18.1)

Comment: Which library does `method` come from?

Comment: Is your `add_cards` method expecting an array, or an array reference?

Comment: Yes it is expecting an array

Comment: Show the code that actually throws the exception, i.e. what is it checking?

Comment: Oh it uses this `use Method::Signatures;`

Comment: Show how you declare `addCards`

Comment: It's in my post man

Comment: No, you only show how `buildStarterDeck` is declared.

Comment: well the addCards method is empty I haven't wrote anything in there

Comment: So maybe you are hitting a default setting of `Method::Signatures` ?

Comment: I'm not really sure xd

Comment: From the perldoc: `One of the best ways to figure out what Method::Signatures is doing is to run your code through B::Deparse (run the code with -MO=Deparse).

Setting the METHOD_SIGNATURES_DEBUG environment variable will cause Method::Signatures to display debugging information when it is compiling signatures.`

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: `METHOD_SIGNATURES_DEBUG=1 perl my_script.pl`

Comment: It didn't work at all

Comment: try `perl -MO=Deparse my_script.pl`

Comment: Please edit your answer and put all the information in there instead of creating lots of comments where readers have to piece together what you're asking.

Comment: @RyanFuhrman  This may or may not be related to the problem you are asking about, but this is wrong: `my (@stackone, @stacktwo) = get_cards;` -- whatever `get_cards` returns will all go into `@stackone` and `@stacktwo` will be empty. It's just how a function return works.

Comment: @RyanFuhrman: While your `addCards` method may be empty, it is the prototype that causes the error message you are reporting. Please show your "empty" `addCards` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your definition of `addCards` which you persist in hiding from us despite multiple requests to see it. It must look something like this

```
method addCards($param) {
    ...;
}
```

But you are passing it a ten-element list in `$self->addCards($self->buildStarterDeck)` so the `given too many arguments` error is raised. You don't explain what you want it to do, but something like this is probably more appropriate

```
method addCards(@cards) {
    ...;
}
```

You really shouldn't declare subroutines inside other subroutines. It doesn't limit the scope of the inner subroutine, but you can create a closure over variables declared in the outer subroutine that doesn't work properly

Also bearing in mind [zdim's warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516547/was-given-too-many-arguments-it-expects-1-perl#comment64431931_38516547) from the comments, your code should look more like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Method::Signatures;

method buildStarterDeck {

    my @stack = get_cards;
}

sub get_cards {

    my @start_cards = (1, 6, 9, 14, 17, 20, 22, 23, 26);
    my @power_cards = (73, 81, 89);

    $power_card = $power_cards[rand @power_cards];

    return (@start_cards, $power_card);
}
```

Comment: Well the addCards should add the list of cards into the database column `cards` in a order of using | to separate them